# How to use custom view inside recyclerview item?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) inside each item of RecyclerView.

> **It works fine without [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) but the Exception comes I use this ProgressWheel inside RecyclerView item.**

Everytime, it is giving me the following exception after adding ProgressWheel:

```
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.example.v2.adapter.WallpaperRVGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WallpaperRVGridAdapter.java:131)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.example.v2.adapter.WallpaperRVGridAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(WallpaperRVGridAdapter.java:1)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4385)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3700)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3609)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1859)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:356)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1274)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:525)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:151)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2118)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2415)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
05-04 18:33:06.311: E/AndroidRuntime(738):  at andro
```

**Layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ximgvwWallpaperThumb"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wallpaper_thumb_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/wallpaper_thumb_size"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ximgvwWallpaperDownload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ximgvwWallThumb"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_download_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.todddavies.components.progressbar.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/xprogbarWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        ProgressWheel:barColor="#ff9a0000"
        ProgressWheel:barLength="30dp"
        ProgressWheel:barWidth="10dp"
        ProgressWheel:rimColor="#FFF"
        ProgressWheel:rimWidth="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapter Methods:**

```
@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wallpaper_grid_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Show your xml files for activity/fragment and for recyclerview item, please.
Source code will be good too

Comment: @ScionofIkshvaku does it work fine without the progresswheel?

Comment: @Smashing yes it works fine without ProgressWheel.

Comment: RelativeLayout shouldn't have the android:orientation property.

Comment: @vovahost that doesn't matter here

Comment: Did you try to use this Wheel without RecyclerView?

Comment: @krossovochkin yes,i have already used it with `ListView` that works fine. Now, i want to change `ListView` to `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Are you sure that the path is right *com.todddavies.components.progressbar.ProgressWheel* ?

Comment: @vovahost yes it is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, resolved it by using different Custom ProgressBar view [DonutProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/lzyzsd/circleprogress/DonutProgress.java) instead of [ProgressWHeel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel).

This seems like there is something wrong in [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) but couldn't find the exact cause for it.